# Center of the dual of a Lie algebra

Tags: terminology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra. Let $C \subset \mathfrak{g}^*$ be the subspace of linear forms that vanish on Lie brackets:
$$C = \{\alpha \in \mathfrak{g}^*, ~ [\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g}] \subset \ker \alpha\}$$

If I'm not mistaken, $C$ can also be described as the fixed points of the coadjoint action, or as the first cohomology space $H^1(\mathfrak{g}, \mathbb{R})$.

Apparently, some people also call it the "center" of $\mathfrak{g}^*$. Why?

Comment: Perhaps it is the center of $\mathfrak g^*$ with respect to the [cocommutator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_coalgebra).

Comment: Yeah? In what sense?

Comment: In [this sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra#Subalgebras.2C_ideals.2C_and_homomorphisms); that is, maybe we have $C = \{\alpha \in \mathfrak g^*: [\alpha,\mathfrak g^*] = 0 \}$ where $[\cdot,\cdot]$ denotes the cocommutator.

Comment: I don't think that makes sense, the cocommutator is not something  that eats two elements of $\mathfrak{g}^*$